# Server log processing in Spark- Regex or Elastic Search?

Tags: apache-spark, logging, elasticsearch

One small question if you can help me out. I am working on log processing in Spark. I am using regular expressions (Regex) for pattern matching and then do further analysis on the identifies pieces. Ip, username, date etc. Is this good approach? Shall I go for elastic search for pattern matching? What will be your take on this.

Comment: I think it's fine with the regex. Why putting so much overhead with elastic search just for matching and ip, userame, etc. I think regex is ok for logs, that anyway are structured by some patterns

Comment: Actually Elasticsearch doesn't do pattern matching (string parsing?) per se, it is the job of Logstash or which ever system is pushing data to ES.